# Select a value for a Picker by tapping on the whole row

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm building a SwiftUI app that has a `Picker` view. It is embedded inside a `NavigationView`, so as I tap on the title of the `Picker`, I get forwarded to a fullscreen selection view to select a value. I can select one only by tapping on the `Text` itself, but nothing happens if I tap outside the red area.
[image: areas of interaction on a screen]

I wonder is this an expected behaviour or some kind of a bug? Can it be fixed so tap on any part of the row will count as a selection?
The code is following:

```swift
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        Form {
            Section {
                TextField("Amount", text: $checkAmount)
                    .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
                // !!!
                // The picker is here
                // !!!
                Picker("Number of people", selection: $peopleIndex) {
                    ForEach(peopleRange) {
                        Text("\($0) people")
                    }
                }
            }

            Section(header: Text("How much tip do you want to leave?")) {
                Picker("Tip percentage", selection: $percentageIndex) {
                    ForEach(0 ..< tipPercentages.count) {
                        Text("\(self.tipPercentages[$0])%")
                    }
                }.pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
            }

            Section {
                Text("$\(totalPerPerson, specifier: "%.2f")")
            }
        }.navigationBarTitle("WeSplit")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try .contentShape(Rectangle())

```
ForEach(peopleRange) {
    HStack {
        Text("\($0) people")
        Spacer()
    }
    .contentShape(Rectangle())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this behaviour is a bug and will be fixed in the Xcode 11.2

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select all the row you can use an HStack with Spacer:

```
ForEach(peopleRange) {
    HStack {
        Text("\($0) people")
        Spacer()
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work using Xcode 11.1 / iOS 13.1

Comment: I tried it in an example project (Xcode11.1 iOS13.1) with the first part of your code and it works for me :/ adding the spacer the whole row is selectable.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this help you or give you some ideas.

```
  Picker("Number of people", selection: $peopleIndex) {
                ForEach(1..<100) { index in
                    ZStack{
                        Color.white
                        Text("\(index) people")
                    }

                }
            }
```